# Are cleric domain spells unlimited like cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, cleric

I'm trying to make a level 1 Cleric. I'm going to use the Life Domain; at level 1 it says the Domain spells are Bless and Cure Wounds.  It also says they are always prepared and don't use up a spell slot when cast.

Can I use these two Domain spells as often as I use cantrips, or do I have limited number of uses per day/long rest?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a Q&A site, please ask the question you want answered and leave out the irrelevancies. We also appreciate you taking the time to use proper grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 22):

It means what it says:

> Once you gain a domain spell, you always 
>   have it prepared, and it doesn’t count against the 
>   number of spells you can prepare each day.

You always have it prepared. It doesn't count against spells you prepare. It says nothing about not using slots to cast, so it does.

A cleric can prepare a given number of spells *plus* their domain spells. Casting any of these prepared spells uses a spell slot.

Comment: If it *did* say you can cast it without using a spell slot then it wouldn't use a spell slot.  It's only the situation the OP is describing not matching reality that leads to your answer being correct.